# Alpakka Consumer not consuming messages from Kafka running via Docker compose

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, docker-compose, kafka-consumer-api, alpakka

I've got Kafka and Zookeeper running via Docker compose. I'm able to send/consume messages to a topic using Kafka terminal and I'm able to monitor everything via Conduktor. But unfortunately, I'm not being able to consume msgs via my Scala app using Alpakka connector. The app connects to the topic but whenever I send a msg to the topic nothing happens.

Just Kafka and Zookeeper are running via docker-compose. I'm running Scala consumer app directly in the host machine.

**Docker Compose**

```
version: '3'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      HOSTNAME_COMMAND: "route -n | awk '/UG[ \t]/{print $$2}'"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

**Scala App**

```
object Main extends App {
  implicit val actorSystem = ActorSystem()

  import actorSystem.dispatcher

  val kafkaConsumerSettings = ConsumerSettings(actorSystem, new StringDeserializer, new StringDeserializer)
    .withGroupId("new_id")
    .withCommitRefreshInterval(1.seconds)
    .withProperty(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest")
    .withBootstrapServers("localhost:9092")

  Consumer
    .plainSource(kafkaConsumerSettings, Subscriptions.topics("test1"))
    .map(msg => msg.value())
    .runWith(Sink.foreach(println)).onComplete {
    case Failure(exception) => exception.printStackTrace()
    case Success(value) => println("done")
  }
}
```

**App - Console output**

```
16:58:33.877 INFO  [akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger]                     Slf4jLogger started
16:58:34.470 INFO  [akka.kafka.internal.SingleSourceLogic]            [1955f] Starting. StageActor Actor[akka://default/system/Materializers/StreamSupervisor-0/$$a#-591284224]
16:58:34.516 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig] ConsumerConfig values: 
    allow.auto.create.topics = true
    auto.commit.interval.ms = 5000
    auto.offset.reset = earliest
    bootstrap.servers = [localhost:9092]
    check.crcs = true
    client.dns.lookup = default
    client.id = 
    client.rack = 
    connections.max.idle.ms = 540000
    default.api.timeout.ms = 60000
    enable.auto.commit = false
    exclude.internal.topics = true
    fetch.max.bytes = 52428800
    fetch.max.wait.ms = 500
    fetch.min.bytes = 1
    group.id = novo_id
    group.instance.id = null
    heartbeat.interval.ms = 3000
    interceptor.classes = []
    internal.leave.group.on.close = true
    isolation.level = read_uncommitted
    key.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
    max.partition.fetch.bytes = 1048576
    max.poll.interval.ms = 300000
    max.poll.records = 500
    metadata.max.age.ms = 300000
    metric.reporters = []
    metrics.num.samples = 2
    metrics.recording.level = INFO
    metrics.sample.window.ms = 30000
    partition.assignment.strategy = [class org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RangeAssignor]
    receive.buffer.bytes = 65536
    reconnect.backoff.max.ms = 1000
    reconnect.backoff.ms = 50
    request.timeout.ms = 30000
    retry.backoff.ms = 100
    sasl.client.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.jaas.config = null
    sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd = /usr/bin/kinit
    sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin = 60000
    sasl.kerberos.service.name = null
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.callback.handler.class = null
    sasl.login.class = null
    sasl.login.refresh.buffer.seconds = 300
    sasl.login.refresh.min.period.seconds = 60
    sasl.login.refresh.window.factor = 0.8
    sasl.login.refresh.window.jitter = 0.05
    sasl.mechanism = GSSAPI
    security.protocol = PLAINTEXT
    security.providers = null
    send.buffer.bytes = 131072
    session.timeout.ms = 10000
    ssl.cipher.suites = null
    ssl.enabled.protocols = [TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1]
    ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm = https
    ssl.key.password = null
    ssl.keymanager.algorithm = SunX509
    ssl.keystore.location = null
    ssl.keystore.password = null
    ssl.keystore.type = JKS
    ssl.protocol = TLS
    ssl.provider = null
    ssl.secure.random.implementation = null
    ssl.trustmanager.algorithm = PKIX
    ssl.truststore.location = null
    ssl.truststore.password = null
    ssl.truststore.type = JKS
    value.deserializer = class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer

16:58:34.701 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]      Kafka version: 2.4.0
16:58:34.702 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]      Kafka commitId: 77a89fcf8d7fa018
16:58:34.702 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser]      Kafka startTimeMs: 1585256314699
16:58:34.715 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer]  [Consumer clientId=consumer-novo_id-1, groupId=novo_id] Subscribed to topic(s): test1
16:58:35.308 INFO  [org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata]                [Consumer clientId=consumer-novo_id-1, groupId=novo_id] Cluster ID: c2XBuDIJTI-gBs9guTvG
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Export [`KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS`](https://docs.confluent.io/current/installation/docker/config-reference.html#confluent-kafka-configuration)**

> Describes how the host name that is advertised and can be reached by
>   clients. The value is published to ZooKeeper for clients to use.
>
> If using the `SSL` or `SASL` protocol, the endpoint value must specify the
>   protocols in the following formats:
>
> - SSL: `SSL://` or `SASL_SSL://`
> - SASL: `SASL_PLAINTEXT://` or `SASL_SSL://`

```
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS=PLAINTEXT://localhost:29092
```

---

And now your consumer can use port `29092`:

```
.withBootstrapServers("localhost:29092")
```

Comment: @vinyoliver Did it fix your problem?

Comment: Yeah, it did! For those who are facing the same problem, here you go my docker-compose with the required changes: https://gist.github.com/vinyoliver/b93116d13be8d8b45a3650122dc17bf6